# Transform Array to Uppercase letters

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having an issue with my code, and can't get it to work with either strtoupper or array_change_key_case(array, CASE_UPPER).

I'm using the following code to save a post title in WP from some custom fields. Can someone help me format it order to transform the array to uppercase and then save that value?

```
function taktiko_mitroo_title_updater( $post_id )

{
    
    if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'taktiko-mitroo' ) {

        $my_post = array();
        $my_post['ID'] = $post_id;
        $my_post['post_title'] = get_field( 'doctors_lname', $post_id ) . ' ' . substr(get_field( 'doctors_fname', $post_id ), 0, 30) ;
        
        
        wp_update_post ( $my_post ) ; 

    }

}
 
// run after ACF saves the $_POST['fields'] data

add_action('acf/save_post', 'taktiko_mitroo_title_updater');
```

Tried using the following after $my_post and then update post with $upper_post with no success

```
$upper_post = array_change_key_case($my_post, CASE_UPPER);
```

Comment: What is the reason for using substr?
This function is longer for text letters than text Use the ucfirst function for uppercase

Comment: Isn't ucfirst just for Capitalizing the first letter? I kinda need to make them all uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue thanks to Morteza Barati stating the substr function.

Code ended as

```
function taktiko_mitroo_title_updater( $post_id )

{
    
    if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'taktiko-mitroo' ) {

        $my_post = array();
        $my_post['ID'] = $post_id;
        $my_post['post_title'] = strtoupper(get_field( 'doctors_lname', $post_id )) . ' ' . strtoupper(get_field( 'doctors_fname', $post_id )) ;
        
        
        wp_update_post ( $my_post ) ; 

    }

}
 
// run after ACF saves the $_POST['fields'] data

add_action('acf/save_post', 'taktiko_mitroo_title_updater');`
```